# Conditional for-each loop is not working in xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0, bpel

sample data:

```
    <school>
<student_details>
<student>
<id>1</id>
<name>manju</name>
<subject>
<subject_name>maths</subject_name>
</subject>
<subject>
<subject_name>science</subject_name>
</subject>
</student>
<student>
<id>2</id>
<name>raghu</name>
<subject>
<subject_name>maths</subject_name>
</subject>
<subject>
<subject_name>sanskrit</subject_name>
</subject>
</student>
<student>
<id>3</id>
<name>vijay</name>
<subject>
<subject_name>maths</subject_name>
</subject>
</student>
<student>
<id>4</id>
<name>sunil</name>
<subject>
<subject_name>sanskrit</subject_name>
</subject>
</student>
<student>
<id>5</id>
<name>anil</name>
<subject>
<subject_name>social</subject_name>
</subject>
<subject>
<subject_name>english</subject_name>
</subject>
<subject>
<subject_name>Kannada</subject_name>
</subject>
</student>

<student>
<id>6</id>
<name>midhun</name>
<subject>
<subject_name>social</subject_name>
</subject>
<subject>
<subject_name>sanskrit</subject_name>
</subject>
<subject>
<subject_name>Kannada</subject_name>
</subject>
</student>

</student_details>

<exclude>
<exclude_subjects>
<subject_name>maths</subject_name>
</exclude_subjects>
<exclude_subjects> 
<subject_name>science</subject_name>
</exclude_subjects>
</exculde>


<extra>
<extra_subjects>
<subject_name>sanskrit</subject_name>
</exclude_subjects>
<exclude_subjects> 
<subject_name>arabic</subject_name>
</extra_subjects>
</extra>
</school>
```

below is my xsd :

```
<schema>
    <element name="school">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="student_details>
<complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="student" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="Id" type="sting"/>
    <element name="name" type="sting"/>
    <element name="subject" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="subject_name" type="sting"/>
    </complexType>
    </sequence>
    </element>
    </complexType>
    <sequence>
    </element>
</complexType>
    <sequence>
    </element>

    <element name="exclude">
<complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="exclude_subjects" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="subject_name" type="sting"/>
    </complexType>
    </sequence>
    </element>
    </complexType>
    <sequence>
    </element>

 <element name="extra">
<complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="extra_subjects" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="subject_name" type="sting"/>
    </complexType>
    </sequence>
    </element>
    </complexType>
    <sequence>
    </element>

</complexType>
    <sequence>
    </element>
    </schema>
```

below is my xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="/school">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="student_details/student[subject[not(subject_name = ../../../exclude/exclude_subjects/subject_name and subject_name = ../../../extra/extra_subjects/subject_name)]]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

I would like to get one output when condition is met. Here is the sample xml.

My requirement is if student contains any subject which is not there in the exclude_subjects or if student contains subjects which are present in extra_subjects then  that student name should be assigned to the target without duplicate.

For eg: in the above given sample xml anil ,sunil and midhun names should be assigned to the target.

Please help....

Comment: How is this different from your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201997/exit-from-parent-loop-is-not-working-in-xslt

Comment: almost similar but here one more condition added to check extra_subjects.

Comment: if student contains any subject which is not there in the exclude_subjects or if student contains subjects which are present in extra_subjects then that student name should be assigned to the target without duplicate...for this requirement i have added AND OR combination in the xslt..but its not working

Comment: Michael..adding to the above point..XSD has been changed with adding extra_subjects.. pls help